# Why use wollen in this context?

Tags: verb-usage

This sentence appears in Anthony Doerr's Alles Licht, das wir nicht sehen, Aus dem Englischen von Werner Löcher-Lawrence:

> Er hat jeden Test ausgeführt, der ihm einfallen **wollte** und der sich ohne eine weitere Person durchführen ließ.

What is the explanation for the use of wollen in this sentence? Why was it not written this way?

> Er hat jeden Test ausgeführt, der ihm **einfiel**, und der sich ohne eine weitere Person durchführen ließ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the so called subjective use of modals. There is a fixed phrase

> Es will mir nicht einfallen.

which means roughly *The thought doesn't **want** to come to me.* and your example plays with that phrase. He did every test that wanted to come to his mind. So he hasn't got full control of the selection of the tests as some may have decided not to come to his mind. They are like revelations of a sort.